# What does the rainbow poop do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I ran into this rainbow poop.

[image: Rainbow Poop]

Breaking it caused a nice sound effect and a rainbow to pop up on the screen. Did it do something else too, or is that all it does? Was I unlucky and got something I already had, like full health?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is all we know so far:

> - Causes a rainbow to appear on the screen
> - Can also drop coins, keys bombs or hearts.
> - Gives full health upon destruction.

from [bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Poop#Rainbow_Poop)

Comment: Rainbow poop only affects the player; co-op buddies do not get healed by it.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, it restores full health.

Answer (score -2):

I had a familliar, the BFF, the friendly fly, and it had died, then I broke the poop, it revived him.